# How to add field to existing Embed (Discord.js v14)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I get an embed out of a message and I want to add a field and then edit the message. Before I upgraded to v14, I could just do embed.addFields(). But now, when doing this, it just removes every property (color, description, etc.) from the embed, except for the field I add.

```
  let embed = new EmbedBuilder(msg.embeds[0])
  embed.addFields({name:'\u200B', value:`${emoji} ${role}`, inline:false})
  msg.edit({embeds: [embed]})
  msg.react(emoji);
```

I have also tried `embed.fields.push()`, but that also hasn't worked (the console says the function is undefined).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new EmbedBuilder()` doesn't accept an `Embed` as the parameter. Use `.data`, `.toJSON()` or `EmbedBuilder.from()` (which does accept an `Embed`)

```js
new EmbedBuilder(msg.embeds[0].data)
new EmbedBuilder(msg.embeds[0].toJSON())
EmbedBuilder.from(msg.embeds[0])
```

any of the lines above will work

Answer (score 1):

Try `EmbedBuilder.from(msg.embeds[0])` instead of `new EmbedBuilder(msg.embeds[0])`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).